# Better way to convert string to string literal in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a third party that has defined

```
editorStylingMode?: 'outlined' | 'underlined' | 'filled';
```

and now I set the value in my `environment.ts` (in Angular) as below

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    editorStylingMode: 'filled'
};
```

then I get an error in my code when assigning the value from environment

```
config({
    editorStylingMode: environment.editorStylingMode,
});
```

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"filled" | "outlined" | "underlined"'

I tried these below solutions and they work

### Solution 1

```
    config({
        editorStylingMode: environment.editorStylingMode as 'filled' | 'outlined' | 'underlined',
    });
```

### Solution 2

```
export const environment: {
    production: boolean,
    editorStylingMode: 'filled' | 'outlined' | 'underlined',
} = {
    production: false,
    editorStylingMode: 'filled'
};
```

Just wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

If your `environment` is meant to be readonly (and by the `const` I am assuming it is the intent even though `const` does not ensure deep immutability) the you can use a `as const` assertion on `environment`:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    editorStylingMode: 'filled'
} as const;
```

This will make the object type `readonly` but it will also preserve all literal types. You could also just use `as const` on the field to preserve the literal type:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    editorStylingMode: 'filled' as const
};
```

These options both might cause problems if typescript can figure out a branch can't be taken because of the specific values. Another option to avoid duplication is to use a type query to get to the union you want.

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    editorStylingMode: 'filled' as Exclude<TypeFromLibThatCOntainsTheField['editorStylingMode'], null | undefined>
};
```

Or if that type can't be referenced you can use the function parameter:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    editorStylingMode: 'filled' as Exclude<Parameters<typeof config>[0]['editorStylingMode'], null | undefined>
};
```

Neither of these are necessarily shorter but they avoid the duplication.

Answer (score 2):

The cleaner way is the following :

**Environment.interface.ts**:

```
  export interface Environment {
      production: boolean;
      editorStylingMode: 'filled' | 'outlined' | 'underlined',
    }
```

**Environment.ts**:

```
import { Environment } from './environment.interface';

export const environment: Environment = {
  production: false,
  editorStylingMode: 'filled'
};
```

This is because we create an *interface* which explicitly lists the properties needed in the environment object.

Comment: *why* is this is a cleaner way though?

Comment: because we create an interface which clearly depicts the properties and type of class const can be defined as shown above.

Comment: it's like the second solution in my answer ;)

Comment: @RezaRahmati ah we answered at the same time... , we are also using the above approach...  :P

Answer (score 2):

I'd start off by creating `type EditorStylingMode = "outlined" | "underlined" | "filled"` to make your type assertions a bit easier. It also centralizes your definition of what valid values exist for `EditorStylingMode` (e.g. if you add a new option to `EditorStylingMode`, you wouldn't want have to update every instance of `"outlined" | "underlined" | "filled"` throughout your application)

Then you can export the `environment` as:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    editorStylingMode: 'filled' as EditorStylingMode,
};
```

Config would just be:

```
config({
    editorStylingMode: environment.editorStylingMode,
})
```

Or even better, you can define a type for `environment` as:

```
// environment.js
export interface Environment {
    production: bool;
    editorStylingMode: EditorStylingMode,
}

export const environment: Environment = {
    production: true,
    editorStylingMode: 'filled',
};
```

In both these solutions, you keep the `environment` properly typed as you'd expect. But with the second option you can also import the `Environment` type by itself and use it elsewhere. For example, this makes it possible to declare `config` as:

```
// config.js
import { Environment } from "./environment";

export function config(env: Environment) { ... }

...

// main.js
import { environment } from "./environment";
import { config } from "./config";

config(environment);
```

Comment: this issue is the config method and type literals are coming from a third party library, I am not able to change them

Comment: @RezaRahmati Fair enough. The intent of the last section was to provide an example of how another file could reference the *type* of `environment` without having to reference the value `environment`. The could be useful if you have a different environment file for staging or QA, or you might need to create a function that returns a valid `Environment`. However, if you never actually need this in your project, then by means, don't worry about writing that interface.